# Is it possible for Elasticsearch to put alias name for index patterns for future indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that I can put alias names for existing indexes via

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "my-index-000001", "alias" : "alias1" } }
    ]
}
```

or (seems to be equal in outcome)

```
PUT /my-index-000001/_alias/alias1
```

but is it also possible to create an alias via patterns, so that new created indexes already come with an alias?

so when i do this:

```
POST /_aliases
    {
        "actions" : [
            { "add" : { "index" : "my-index-*", "alias" : "alias1" } }
        ]
    }
```

All indexes created in the future which match pattern *my-index-** will automatically come with alias *alias1*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this using an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html):

```
PUT _index_template/my_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["my-index-*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "aliases": {
      "alias1": { }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if you're on a version [before 7.8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/indices-templates.html), the syntax is a little bit different:

```
PUT _template/my_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["my-index-*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "aliases": {
    "alias1": { }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you can see this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html). You need to define an index template.

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
    "index_patterns" : ["te*"],
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "aliases" : {
        "alias1" : {}
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `current` instead, so the link will always point to the most recent version ;-)

Comment: cool thx! can this also be achieved via config file? i suppose no?

Comment: You're Welcome. It seems there were such option but has been removed since elasticsearch 1.5 . It is mentioned [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10870).